# How to fetch all custom options from product

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I have a stock product with some custom options. I would like to fetch the custom options for this product in the view.phtml of my rwd-based theme.

Now I thought this would be possible through

```
$myoptions = $_product->getOptions();
print_r($myoptions);
```

But instead of giving me back the options, the page loads for a long time and then outputs lots of unrelated stuff. At least it looks like this.

Is this the right way to fetch the custom options of a product? Is there another (better) way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be somewhat like:-

```
$productSku = "ABCDE";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $product->getIdBySku( $productSku );
$product->load($productId);

/**
 * In Magento Models or database schema level, the product's Custom Options are
 * executed & maintained as only "options". So, when checking whether any product has
 * Custom Options or not, we should check by using this method "hasOptions()" only.
 */
if($product->hasOptions()) {
    echo '<pre>';

    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
        $optionType = $o->getType();
        echo 'Type = '.$optionType;

        if ($optionType == 'drop_down') {
            $values = $o->getValues();

            foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                print_r($v);
            }
        }
        else {
            print_r($o);
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work. The product page is showing the custom options just fine with its standard behaviour, but has_options() does not return a result, just like there are none.